# Android issue when Integrating Google Sign-in API

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-oauth, google-signin

I am trying to add Google Sign-in functionality to my Android App. I followed the steps mentioned [HERE](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating) and I successfully managed to get the configuration file provided by Google.

But I faced an issue when trying to execute the step which says **"Add the configuration file to your project"** along with the following description.

> Copy the google-services.json file you just downloaded into the app/
>   or mobile/ directory of your Android Studio project. Open the Android
>   Studio Terminal pane:
>
> $ mv path-to-download/Downloads/google-services.json app/

I am guessing they want me to type that in to my Android Studio terminal and replace the path-to-download with the path of my app on my Mac?

So this is what I tried:

```
$ mv /Users/Earthling/AndroidStudioProjects/MyMobileApp/app/google-services.json
```

This returns me an error from the terminal that says:

**bash: $: command not found**

What am I doing wrong? Did I misunderstand the step?

Comment: **Quick work-around** : Just paste the file manually instead of that command.

Comment: Umm I pasted that manually... so that means I dont need that command? :O @UmaKanth I thought you needed both haha

Comment: No you don't need the command. The command itself is to move that file from one directory to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that

[`mv` command](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/umv.htm) takes 2 arguments. One is the path from which a file is to be moved and other to which it should be moved.

```
$ mv path-to-download/google-services.json app/
```

> Notice the  space in between .json and app

This makes it 2 arguments.

Your command doesn't have 2 arguments. Use this instead.

```
$ mv /Users/Earthling/AndroidStudioProjects/MyMobileApp/app/google-services.json app/
```

Assuming that `/Users/Earthling/AndroidStudioProjects/MyMobileApp/app/google-services.json` is the location which has the json file.